# your page has 5 redirects. .htacces file needs imrovement

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

Google is telling me that I have multiple redirects and this is what I have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\.site1\.com$
RewriteRule !/index.html https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site2.com/$1 [R=301,L]




RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can I improve it so its not such a big hit on performance
I am facing bad performance

Comment: Do you really have both site1.com and site2.com served from one document root?

Comment: yes I do...its a setting in the CMS that I use